# Repeating alarm is not working properly

Tags: android

I am developing an application that needs to fire an alarm after each 5 days, for that i am using setRepeating method,for example : today date is 16 so alarm should fire on 21 but for testing purpose, i changed my device date 16 to 17 and suddenly it fires alarm , however it should start alarm after 5 days, i am not able to find out what i am doing wrong.  Please  help me . Thanks in advance.

```
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        long check = 86400000; // no. of millisecond in days
        int days = Integer.parseInt(strDays);
        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReciever.class);
        intent.putExtra("Item", "Time To Pick Up " + strItemName);
        intent.putExtra("Id", 1);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                getBaseContext(), RQS_1, intent, 0);
long time =check*2; // for 2 days 
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),time,pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read documentation of `setRepeating`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

`alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),time,pendingIntent);`

Here `System.currentTimeMillis()` suggests that alarm should first go off instantaneously and then after 5 days.

> triggerAtMillis   time in milliseconds that the alarm should first go
>   off, using the appropriate clock (depending on the alarm type).

Comment: i am not getting it , can u please explain

Comment: The second parameter in setRepeating call specifies when the alarm should first go off. You should specify today+5 there instead of Current Time.

Comment: means i have to use time parameter there

Comment: 432000000 , https://www.google.co.in/search?q=5+days+to+milliseconds&oq=5+days+to+milliseconds&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i65l2j69i60l3.5686j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8

Comment: and what about third parameter where i am using time

Comment: third parameter specifies the incremental time after which the alarm will fire periodically. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent)

Comment: means i need alarm after each 5 day so i have to use 43200000 on both long parameter